# express nodejs webserver extremely slow, loading times of 4-6 seconds per script/stylesheet

Tags: node.js, performance, express, server

I am developing a [cloud server](https://github.com/stad-nico/File-Server/tree/nav) that serves static files for personal use with express and nodejs. While developing I added some script files until I noticed that the webserver suddenly started to load extremely slow on reloads. I used the chrome dev tools and noticed extreme loading times like 6 seconds for a 265 byte script! (See picture)[image]

What I tried:

- moving the `app.use(express.static(...))` to the very top
- clearing cache and application storage as well as restarting the computer several times
- serving just a very simple HTML-File with no external scripts or stylesheets which of course reduced the loading time severely but `localhost` (265 B) still took 2.03 seconds

I am really confused about this, because it happend out of nowhere from one moment to the next and Ive never experienced this issue while developing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a very stupid mistake: as you can see in the screenshot the throttling is set to `Slow 3G`. Seems that I changed it from `No throttling` by mistake. So check the dev tools settings!